# how to display images from sd card using ImageLoader

Tags: android, image, android-sdcard

I'm Getting MalformedURLException while displaying images from sd card using ImageLoader, it getting error of  **java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: /storage/emulated/0/classnkk_images/3_20150928162260013.png** . Can possible to pass sd card path to imageloader.

Log Cat

```
09-30 06:40:24.056  14267-14343/? W/System.err﹕ java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: /storage/emulated/0/classnkk_images/3_20150928162260013.png
09-30 06:40:24.056  14267-14343/? W/System.err﹕ at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:176)
09-30 06:40:24.056  14267-14343/? W/System.err﹕ at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:125)
09-30 06:40:24.056  14267-14343/? W/System.err﹕ at com.example.tazeen.classnkk.ImageLoader.getBitmap(ImageLoader.java:68)
09-30 06:40:24.056  14267-14343/? W/System.err﹕ at com.example.tazeen.classnkk.ImageLoader.access$000(ImageLoader.java:23)
09-30 06:40:24.056  14267-14343/? W/System.err﹕ at com.example.tazeen.classnkk.ImageLoader$PhotosLoader.run(ImageLoader.java:134)
09-30 06:40:24.056  14267-14343/? W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
09-30 06:40:24.056  14267-14343/? W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
09-30 06:40:24.056  14267-14343/? W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
09-30 06:40:24.056  14267-14343/? W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
09-30 06:40:24.056  14267-14343/? W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Here is my ImageLoader Class

```
public class ImageLoader {

    MemoryCache memoryCache=new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews= Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
    ExecutorService executorService;

    public ImageLoader(Context context){
        fileCache=new FileCache(context);
        executorService= Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }

    int stub_id = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    public void DisplayImage(String url, int loader, ImageView imageView)
    {
        stub_id = loader;
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
        if(bitmap!=null)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
        {
            queuePhoto(url, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(loader);
        }
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView)
    {
        PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url)
    {
        File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

        //from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if(b!=null)
            return b;

        //from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap=null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(8000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(8000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
           return null;
        }
    }

    //decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
        try {
            //decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
            int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
            int scale=1;
            while(true){
                if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale*=2;
            }

            //decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        return null;
    }

    //Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad
    {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
            url=u;
            imageView=i;
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
            this.photoToLoad=photoToLoad;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
            memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
            Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
            a.runOnUiThread(bd);
        }
    }

    boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
        String tag=imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
        if(tag==null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    //Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
    {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p){bitmap=b;photoToLoad=p;}
        public void run()
        {
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            if(bitmap!=null)
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }

}
```

Comment: check your path of image i think its not correct

Comment: So thats why this post this issue , i dont uderstand how to set the internal storage path to ImageLoader

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are having a malformed url - as the error says. 
Therefore check if you have a proper URL.
Something similar to your question:
[MalformedURLException in android when downloading a zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523079/malformedurlexception-in-android-when-downloading-a-zip-file).